# Convert GMT date stamp to my timezone in PHP

Tags: php

I'm not sure what I'm doing is even correct. I'm being given a CSV export of transactions and the date stamp looks like a GMT timestamp to me, but when I try to convert it to my timezone and echo the time I just get the same timestamp.

```
$date = new DateTime('2019-11-12 13:43:12 +1300');
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Auckland')); 
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 1):

The Timezone "Pacific/Auckland" with Daylight Saving Time (DST) is 13 hours ahead of GMT so if you take a date time string with an offset of `+13:00` and set the DateTimeZone to "Pacific/Auckland" you won't see any difference of the time because the offset will be the same. You will only see a difference if you either have a UTC  (ending with `Z`) or GMT date time string (ending with `+00:00`) and converting this to your time zone:

```
$date = new DateTime('2019-11-12 13:43:12+00:00');
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Auckland'));
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:sP");
```